# AS3 - Using sprite sheets to optimize my games

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite

So, I'm trying to make my flash "games" run more smoothly. I am using individual PNG files for each of my objects in order to create player animations.

I've heard from some places that using individual files like that is bad.

I heard about using sprite sheets in order to compress data and reduce memory usage.

Maybe I have it wrong, but is there a way to merge all of my PNG images (with transparency) together in such a way that flash can continue to use the images individually?

I am really looking for ways to make my programs run more smoothly in order to be able to have lots of images on screen without much lag. Any ideas on how I can make things run better?

[Here is an example of a tile based game I'm trying to make that is having serious lag issues.](http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/item/1c55ca8ea8d2d5ab91d8ddd596324d20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Photoshop or similar software you would combine all of the animations frames into one file. The size and shape of the file can be whatever you want, but each of the 'frames' should be the same size, in the same order and with no space between them. For example, lets say each frame is 25x25px, your walk animation is 10 frames and you want the final .png to be one long strip. You would make a new .png with the dimensions of either 250X25 or 25X250 and then insert all of your frames into that one file in the order of the animation. It's up to you if you want to embed these as display object or files that get loaded, but once you have them you just need to use BitmapData to break up the input file into new BitmapData objects and then display them as needed. Going one step further, lets say that most if not all characters have a walk animation and an action animation, you would make a single class to deal with loading character animations and the first row of the image file would be the walk animation and the second would be the action animation.

Comment: Just an FYI you don't need to break them back up. You can use `scrollRect` or similar techniques in stage3d to only display a section of a bitmap

Answer (score 1):

[TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/features) allows merge png files. It generates two files: png and config file. Png is just merged images and config file is txt file which you can load into your swf, parse and demerge your images using it. Config could be in various formats for different game engines.